# Is there a way to navigate to another View without a NavigationLink using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, navigation

I'm new to Swift development and I've been building an app that takes a username and password and should send the user to a new page, but it doesn't do that.

I am using a button that takes a username and password and sends that to a function that eventually will have a database connected with it to check whether the user is in the system or not. It should check if username is "username" and password is "password" and then should change the View to LoggedInView().

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("logo_square")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding(.bottom, 25)
            TextField("0", text: $username, prompt: Text("Username"))
                .frame(width: 400, height: 40)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .font(Font.system(size:28, design: .default))
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
            SecureField("0", text: $password, prompt: Text("Password"))
                .frame(width: 400, height: 40)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .font(Font.system(size: 28, design: .default))
                .autocapitalization(.none)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {log_in(username: username, password: password)()}) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        Text("Log in")
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(GrowingButton())
                .font(Font.system(size: 24, design: .default))
                .padding(.top, 12)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
        }
        .frame(alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            MainView()
    }
}

struct GrowingButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(.vertical, 15)
            .padding(.horizontal, 150)
            .background(Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 1.2 : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: configuration.isPressed)
    }
}

func log_in(username: String, password: String) -> () -> () {
    return {
        if(username == "username" && password == "password") {
            //Should send to LoggedInView()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I've been using, but can't get the new View to come up.

Comment: `if loggedIn { LoggedInView() } else { NotLoggedInView() }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `@Published` property.  When the value of the property changes, the UI is updated to reflect that change.  UI changes are done via the main thread.  Therefore, use `DispatchQueue.main.asnyc` in order to publish the change of `isLoggedIn` to the main thread.

Create a class that conforms to the `ObservableObject` protocol. We will be referring to this class when updating the auth state.  Within `ContentView` initialise the auth and give it the `@StateObject` property wrapper.  Pass this auth reference in to both `LoggedInView` and `NotLoggedInView`, this allows us to access the class without having to make a new instance.

N.B. Rather than using `@ObservedObject` you could have used `@EnvironmentObject`, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) for more information.

```
class Auth: ObservableObject {
    // Create a published property that can be used to listen for changes
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
    
    func login() -> Void {
        // Use DispatchQueue.main to publish changes to the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
    
    func logout() -> Void {
        // Use DispatchQueue.main to publish changes to the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isLoggedIn = false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // Initialise the Auth object
    @StateObject private var auth: Auth = Auth()
    
    var body: some View {
        // If the user is authenticated show the LoggedInView
        // else show the NotLoggedInView
        if auth.isAuthenticated {
            LoggedInView(auth: auth) // pass the auth object to the LoggedInView
        } else {
            NotLoggedInView(auth: auth)  // pass the auth object to the NotLoggedInView
        }
    }
}

struct LoggedInView: View {
    // Reference the Auth object
    @ObservedObject var auth: Auth
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You are logged in.")
            Button("Logout") {
                // Call the logout function
                auth.logout()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NotLoggedInView: View {
    // Reference the Auth object
    @ObservedObject var auth: Auth
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("You are not logged in.")
            Button("Login") {
                // Call the logout function
                auth.login()
            }
        }
    }
}
```